# How to access created enum in C# from code behind to aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code behind C# code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public enum en
    {
       One,
       Two
    }

}
```

How can I access this created enum in my aspx file? Like using the enum in this code:

```
<%


%>
```

Thanks

Comment: Given your current code you can probably just do `Test.en.One` or something, but I highly suspect it's not so simple.

Comment: Just import the namespace it as `en`? See [@Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx) -- or use the fully qualified name as BoltClock suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work ala BoltClock (en didn't seem like a very good name).

```
namespace Test
{
    public enum MYENUM
    {
        One,
        Two
    }
}

<% Response.Write(Test.MYENUM.One.ToString()); %>
```